# How can I display image in gridview with 3 tier architecture?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

For data access layer:

Source:

```
public string insert_details(bisuness_object user_details)
{

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into tbl_rgsthome values(@firstname,@lastname,@emailid,@password,@address,@upload)", con);
    try
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstname", user_details.firstname_value);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastname", user_details.lastname_value);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@emailid", user_details.emailid_value);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", user_details.pass_value);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", user_details.addr_value);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@upload", user_details.fileupl_value);
      //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@imagepath", user_details.imgpth_value);
        return cmd.ExecuteNonQuery().ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception show_error)
    {
        throw show_error;
    }
    finally
    {
        cmd.Dispose();
        con.Close();
        con.Dispose();
    }

}
```

---

home.aspx:

```
public string getimage(object ob)
{
    string img = @"/image/" + ob.ToString();
    return img;
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (FileUpload1.PostedFile != null  && FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName != "")
    {

        byte[] myimage = new byte[FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength];
        HttpPostedFile Image = FileUpload1.PostedFile;
        Image.InputStream.Read(myimage, 0, (int)FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength);
        bisuness_object bo = new bisuness_object();
        // cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@imagepath", ("@uploadimage") + filename);
        bo.firstname_value = TextBox1.Text;
        bo.lastname_value = TextBox2.Text;
        bo.emailid_value = TextBox3.Text;
        bo.pass_value = TextBox4.Text;
        bo.addr_value = TextBox6.Text;
        bo.fileupl_value = FileUpload1.FileName.ToString();
        bisuness_layer bl = new bisuness_layer();
        bind();

        try
        {
            string result = bl.record_insert(bo);
        }
        catch (Exception info)
        {
            throw info;
        }
        finally
        {
            bo = null;
            bl = null;
            bind();
        }
        TextBox1.Text = "";
        TextBox2.Text = "";
        TextBox3.Text = "";
        TextBox4.Text = "";
        TextBox5.Text = "";
        TextBox6.Text = "";
    }
}
```

how to solve it.....please help me
i want to image in gridview

Comment: Where is you gridview?

Answer (score 1):

bind the image tag inside the  gridview dynamically 
by giving the path dynamically

```
 <asp:Image ID="image" Style="width:100px; height:100px;" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# "~/folder/subfolder/" + Eval("id") +"."+ Eval("imagetype") %>' />
```

and the method for binding the gridview

```
 protected void GetDayoffer()
{

    gridview1.DataSource = bl.method();
    gridview1.DataBind();
}
```

hope this will help you  or recovert the bytes into image again and bind it into gridview